# Why does DELETE leave a lingering effect on performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, delete, truncate

At the end is a test script for comparing the performance between a @table variable and a #temp table.  I think I've set it up correctly - the performance timings are taken *outside* of the DELETE/TRUNCATE commands.  The results that I am getting are as follows (times in milliseconds).

```
@Table Variable  #Temp (delete)  #Temp (truncate)
---------------  --------------  ----------------
5723             5180            5506
15636            14746           7800
14506            14300           5583
14030            15460           5386
16706            16186           5360
```

Just to make sure I'm sane, this shows that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (aka `GetDate()`) is taken at the time of the statement, not of the batch, so there should be no interaction between TRUNCATE/DELETE with the `SET @StartTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` statement.

```
select current_timestamp
waitfor delay '00:00:04'
select current_timestamp

-----------------------
2012-10-21 11:29:20.290

-----------------------
2012-10-21 11:29:24.290
```

It's quite consistent in the jump between the first run and the subsequent runs when DELETE is used to clear the table.  What am I missing in my understanding of **DELETE**?  I have repeated this many times, swapped the order, sized tempdb to not require growth etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #values (
  id int identity primary key, -- will be clustered
  name varchar(100) null,
  number int null,
  type char(3) not null,
  low int null,
  high int null,
  status smallint not null
);
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @values TABLE (
  id int identity primary key clustered,
  name varchar(100) null,
  number int null,
  type char(3) not null,
  low int null,
  high int null,
  status smallint not null
);
DECLARE  @ExecutionTime  TABLE(      Duration bigINT    ) 
DECLARE  @StartTime DATETIME,  @i INT = 1; 
WHILE (@i <= 5) 
  BEGIN 
    DELETE @values;
    DBCC freeproccache With NO_InfoMSGS;
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS With NO_InfoMSGS;
    SET @StartTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- alternate getdate() 
    /****************** measured process ***********************/ 

    INSERT @values SELECT a.* FROM master..spt_values a join master..spt_values b on b.type='P' and b.number < 1000;

    /**************** end measured process *********************/ 
    INSERT @ExecutionTime 
    SELECT DurationInMilliseconds = datediff(ms,@StartTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    SET @i +=  1 
  END -- WHILE 

SELECT DurationInMilliseconds = Duration FROM   @ExecutionTime 
GO 

-- Temporary table
DECLARE  @ExecutionTime  TABLE(      Duration bigINT    ) 
DECLARE  @StartTime DATETIME,  @i INT = 1; 
WHILE (@i <= 5) 
  BEGIN 
    delete #values;
    -- TRUNCATE TABLE #values;
    DBCC freeproccache With NO_InfoMSGS;
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS With NO_InfoMSGS;
    SET @StartTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- alternate getdate() 
    /****************** measured process ***********************/ 

    INSERT #values SELECT a.* FROM master..spt_values a join master..spt_values b on b.type='P' and b.number < 1000;

    /**************** end measured process *********************/ 
    INSERT @ExecutionTime 
    SELECT DurationInMilliseconds = datediff(ms,@StartTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    SET @i +=  1 
  END -- WHILE 

SELECT DurationInMilliseconds = Duration FROM   @ExecutionTime 
GO

DROP TABLE  #values 
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This difference only seems to apply when the object is a B+tree. When removing the `primary key` on the table variable so it is a heap I got the following results

```
2560
2120
2080
2130
2140
```

But with the PK I found a similar pattern in my tests as well with typical results below.

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------------------+
| @table | #table | ##table | [permanent_table] |
+--------+--------+---------+-------------------+
|   2670 |   2683 |    9603 |              9703 |
|   6823 |   6840 |    9723 |              9790 |
|   6813 |   6816 |    9626 |              9703 |
|   6883 |   6816 |    9600 |              9716 |
|   6840 |   6856 |    9610 |              9673 |
+--------+--------+---------+-------------------+
```

My theory is that there there is some optimisation available when doing bulk inserts to local temporary B+ trees that only applies when it does not already have any pages allocated.

I base this on the following observations.

1. When running various versions of your test code I only saw this pattern  with `@table_variables` and `#temp` tables. Not permanent tables in `tempdb` nor `##` tables.
2. In order to get the slower performance it is not necessary to have previously added and removed a large amount of rows from the table. Simply adding a single row and leaving it in there is sufficient.
3. `TRUNCATE` deallocates all pages from the table. `DELETE` will not cause the last page in the table to be deallocated.
4. Using the VS 2012 profiler shows that in the faster case SQL Server uses a different code path. 36% of the time is spent in `sqlmin.dll!RowsetBulk::InsertRow` vs 61% of the time spent in `sqlmin.dll!RowsetNewSS::InsertRow` for the slower case.

Running

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(2,OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#values'),1,NULL, 'DETAILED')
```

after the delete returns

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
| index_level | page_count | record_count | ghost_record_count |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|           0 |          1 |            0 |                  1 |
|           1 |          1 |            1 |                  0 |
|           2 |          1 |            1 |                  0 |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

I found that it was possible to reduce the time discrepancy somewhat by [enabling trace flag 610](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

This had the effect of reducing the *quantity* of logging substantially for the subsequent inserts (down from 350 MB to 103 MB as it no longer logs the individual inserted row values) but this had only a minor improvement in timings for the 2nd and subsequent `@table` , `#table` cases and the gap still remains. The trace flag improved the general performance of inserts to the other two table types significantly.

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------------------+
| @table | #table | ##table | [permanent_table] |
+--------+--------+---------+-------------------+
|   2663 |   2670 |    5403 |              5426 |
|   5390 |   5396 |    5410 |              5403 |
|   5373 |   5390 |    5410 |              5403 |
|   5393 |   5410 |    5406 |              5433 |
|   5386 |   5396 |    5390 |              5420 |
+--------+--------+---------+-------------------+
```

From looking in the transaction log I noticed that the initial inserts against empty local temporary tables seem even more minimally logged (at 96 MB).

Notably these faster inserts had only `657` transactions (`LOP_BEGIN_XACT` /`LOP_COMMIT_XACT` pairs) compared with over `10,000` in the slower cases. In particular `LOP_FORMAT_PAGE` operations seem much reduced. The slower cases have a transaction log entry for this for each page in the table (about `10,270`) compared with only `4` such entries in the fast case.

The log used in all three cases was as follows (I have deleted the log records for updates to system base tables to reduce the amount of text but they are still included in the totals)

#### Logging first insert against `@table_var` (96.5 MB)

```
+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
|       Operation       | Context  |                AllocUnitName                 | Size in Bytes |   Cnt   |
+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
| LOP_BEGIN_XACT        | LCX_NULL | NULL                                         |         83876 |     658 |
| LOP_COMMIT_XACT       | LCX_NULL | NULL                                         |         34164 |     657 |
| LOP_CREATE_ALLOCCHAIN | LCX_NULL | NULL                                         |           120 |       3 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_HEAP | dbo.#531856C7                                |            84 |       1 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_IAM  | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |            84 |       1 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_IAM  | dbo.#531856C7                                |            84 |       1 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_IAM  | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |            84 |       1 |
| LOP_HOBT_DDL          | LCX_NULL | NULL                                         |           216 |       6 |
| LOP_HOBT_DELTA        | LCX_NULL | NULL                                         |           320 |       5 |
| LOP_IDENT_NEWVAL      | LCX_NULL | NULL                                         |     100240000 | 2506000 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS       | LCX_HEAP | dbo.#531856C7                                |            72 |       1 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_IAM  | dbo.#531856C7                                |            88 |       1 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_PFS  | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |        158592 |    1848 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_PFS  | dbo.#531856C7                                |            80 |       1 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_PFS  | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        216016 |    2455 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_GAM  | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |         84360 |    1406 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_GAM  | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        147120 |    2452 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_IAM  | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |         84360 |    1406 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_IAM  | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        147120 |    2452 |
| Total                 | NULL     | NULL                                         |     101209792 | 2519475 |
+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
```

#### Logging subsequent inserts TF 610 off (350 MB)

```
+-----------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
|       Operation       |      Context       |                AllocUnitName                 | Size in Bytes |   Cnt   |
+-----------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
| LOP_BEGIN_CKPT        | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |            96 |       1 |
| LOP_BEGIN_XACT        | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |       1520696 |   12521 |
| LOP_COMMIT_XACT       | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |        651040 |   12520 |
| LOP_CREATE_ALLOCCHAIN | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |            40 |       1 |
| LOP_DELETE_SPLIT      | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |          2160 |      36 |
| LOP_END_CKPT          | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |           136 |       1 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_HEAP           | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |        859236 |   10229 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_IAM            | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |            84 |       1 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE       | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |          3108 |      37 |
| LOP_HOBT_DDL          | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |           648 |      18 |
| LOP_HOBT_DELTA        | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |        657088 |   10267 |
| LOP_IDENT_NEWVAL      | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |     100239960 | 2505999 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS       | LCX_CLUSTERED      | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |     258628000 | 2506000 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS       | LCX_HEAP           | dbo.#531856C7                                |            72 |       1 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS       | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |       1042776 |   10302 |
| LOP_MODIFY_HEADER     | LCX_HEAP           | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |        859236 |   10229 |
| LOP_MODIFY_HEADER     | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |          3192 |      38 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_IAM            | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |           704 |       8 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_PFS            | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |        934264 |   11550 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW        | LCX_PFS            | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        783984 |    8909 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_GAM            | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |         76980 |    1283 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_GAM            | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        534480 |    8908 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_IAM            | dbo.#4F47C5E3.PK__#4F47C5E__3213E83F51300E55 |         76980 |    1283 |
| LOP_SET_BITS          | LCX_IAM            | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        534480 |    8908 |
| LOP_SHRINK_NOOP       | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |            32 |       1 |
| LOP_XACT_CKPT         | LCX_NULL           | NULL                                         |            92 |       1 |
| Total                 | NULL               | NULL                                         |     367438748 | 5119297 |
+-----------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
```

#### Logging subsequent inserts TF 610 on (103 MB)

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
|        Operation        |         Context         |                AllocUnitName                 | Size in Bytes |   Cnt   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
| LOP_BEGIN_CKPT          | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |           192 |       2 |
| LOP_BEGIN_XACT          | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |       1339796 |   11099 |
| LOP_BULK_EXT_ALLOCATION | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |         20616 |     162 |
| LOP_COMMIT_XACT         | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |        577096 |   11098 |
| LOP_CREATE_ALLOCCHAIN   | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |            40 |       1 |
| LOP_DELETE_SPLIT        | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR      | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |          2160 |      36 |
| LOP_END_CKPT            | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |           272 |       2 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE         | LCX_BULK_OPERATION_PAGE | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |        863520 |   10280 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE         | LCX_IAM                 | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |            84 |       1 |
| LOP_FORMAT_PAGE         | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR      | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |          3108 |      37 |
| LOP_HOBT_DELTA          | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |        666496 |   10414 |
| LOP_IDENT_NEWVAL        | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |     100239960 | 2505999 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS         | LCX_CLUSTERED           | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |         23544 |     218 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS         | LCX_HEAP                | dbo.#719CDDE7                                |            72 |       1 |
| LOP_INSERT_ROWS         | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR      | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |       1042776 |   10302 |
| LOP_MODIFY_HEADER       | LCX_BULK_OPERATION_PAGE | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |        780216 |   10266 |
| LOP_MODIFY_HEADER       | LCX_HEAP                | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |       1718472 |   20458 |
| LOP_MODIFY_HEADER       | LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR      | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |          3192 |      38 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW          | LCX_IAM                 | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |           704 |       8 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW          | LCX_PFS                 | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |        114832 |    1307 |
| LOP_MODIFY_ROW          | LCX_PFS                 | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        231696 |    2633 |
| LOP_RANGE_INSERT        | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |            48 |       1 |
| LOP_SET_BITS            | LCX_GAM                 | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |         77100 |    1285 |
| LOP_SET_BITS            | LCX_GAM                 | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        157920 |    2632 |
| LOP_SET_BITS            | LCX_IAM                 | dbo.#6DCC4D03.PK__#6DCC4D0__3213E83F6FB49575 |         77100 |    1285 |
| LOP_SET_BITS            | LCX_IAM                 | Unknown Alloc Unit                           |        157920 |    2632 |
| LOP_XACT_CKPT           | LCX_NULL                | NULL                                         |            92 |       1 |
| Total                   | NULL                    | NULL                                         |     108102960 | 2602218 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed confirmation. So the question still bides, why DELETE isn't returning the table to **truly** empty, using your term. Also, this would argue for using #temp tables if clear/populate is used in a batch processing loop.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - The benefit of `TRUNCATE` over `DELETE` on its own would also argue for that. I would also rarely  consider table variables for large numbers of rows.

Comment: This will sound lazy, but wouldn't repeating a 1 to 10-record (variable) insert 1000 times in a batch show the same symptoms? The usage of a large number of rows is only to exacerbate the issue, and provide scale to better see the difference. The gist of the question is to prove one way or another that #temp tables would be better, once we know what the difference is.

Comment: Well my theory is that it is the allocation of the `10,000+` pages which happens in a much more optimized way and seems to avoid some per page overhead. For smaller inserts I would expect any such difference to be less significant.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - Thanks! There is probably more to say on this. As I'll try upgrading to the same version as SQL Kiwi and seeing if I still see the different code paths. If so maybe it is hardware dependant that it makes such a difference (my tests have been on my desktop PC with all data and log files on the same SSD)

Answer (score 0):

Observation and speculation . . .

On some systems, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is defined to be the time at the start of the current transaction. A quick search turned up no definitive documentation of how CURRENT_TIMESTAMP behaves on SQL Server. But SQL Server's default mode is to autocommit transactions, and there's no BEGIN TRANSACTION here, so it *ought* to be the time immediately before the INSERT statement. (The DELETE statement should automatically commit, and whichever way CURRENT_TIMESTAMP works on SQL Server, it shouldn't have anything to do with the DELETE statement when you're using automatically committed transactions.)

On the first iteration, the DELETE statement doesn't have any real work to do, and there aren't any individual rows to log. Maybe the optimizer knows that, and that's reducing the time for the first iteration. (The combination of no rows to delete, and no individual rows to log.)

You could test that (I think) by inserting before deleting.

Comment: I'm going to stop answering questions today. Or whatever it is I'm doing when I type things into that box.

Comment: Should this answer be deleted as obsolete, tangential and distracting?