# Difference between DROP and TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql, truncate, drop-table

What does the `TRUNCATE` do differently to drop?

I believe it deletes all the data in the table but keeps the table name in the database, where as `DROP` deletes all data and the table. Is this correct ?

Comment: Related (and probably a lot of the concepts will be similar or identical, even if not all of the fine details are): http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/delete-vs-truncate

Answer (score 22):

**DELETE - DATA MANIPULATION LANGUAGE(DML)**

The `DELETE` statement in any RDBMS is considered a [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statement.  Also known as CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete), this kind of statement is intended to manipulate data in a database without affecting the underlying structure of the objects.  What this means in practical term is:

- A `DELETE` statement can be fine-tuned using a predicate via either `WHERE` or `JOIN` to delete some or all rows in a table.
- A `DELETE` statement will be logged by the database and can be rolled back within a transaction if the statement fails.
- Typically a `DELETE` will take row level locks on the data it is deleted, though this could escalate higher as necessary.
- Because of the transactional overhead, `DELETE` can be "slow" (this is relative), but safer because it is fine-grained.

**TRUNCATE - DATA DEFINITION LANGUAGE(DDL)**

`TRUCNATE` is considered a [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statement, meaning that it is intended to alter how objects are defined in a database.  Usually, DDL statements are `CREATE`, `ALTER`, or `DROP`, but `TRUNCATE` serves a particular purpose, that of "resettting" a table by removing all the rows.  The methods of this differ between the RDBMS engines and I would recommend looking at the [specifics of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html). The practical implications of a `TRUNCATE` are:

- `TRUNCATE` can not be fine grained.  If successful, it will remove all the rows from your table.
- `TRUNCATE` is typically not logged.  This varies by RDBMS and I would suggest you looks more specifically at how MySQL handles it. (Hint, it varies by version.)
- `TRUNCATE` requires a table metadata lock to execute.  How this is actually implemented can be specific to RDBMS, but essentially the `TRUNCATE` process must prevent other processes from mucking with the table in order to execute its DDL.
- Because it is (typically) not logged and does not use predicates, a `TRUNCATE` will be faster than a `DELETE`, but less safe.

**DROP TABLE - DATA DEFINITION LANGUAGE(DDL)**

`DROP TABLE` goes further than a `TRUNCATE` in that it actually removes the table from the database completely.  This includes removing all associated objects, such as indexes and constraints.  If you dropped a table, not only would you remove all the data, but the structure as well.  This will usually be done when a table is no longer needed.  The primary concern is that since a `DROP` is DDL, you [typically can't undo it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html).  Some RDBMS engines will allow you to wrap DDL within a transaction so you can roll it back, but this is not considered best practice and should be avoided.

Comment: I would add that TRUNCATE resets the table's auto-increment counter.

Answer (score 5):

Although I cannot speak for MySQL, here's a quick table comparing some aspects of truncate vs. delete within Oracle.

```
truncate                             |   delete
---------------------------------    |   ---------------------------
DDL   (implicitly commits,           |   DML
    including any pending DML)       |  
Does not generate undo info          |   Generates undo info
    (rollback statements)            |       (rollback statements)
Resets high water mark in table      |   Does not affect full-scan 
    and all indexes, improving       |       performance
    full-scan performance            |      
Does not fire any delete triggers    |   Fires delete triggers
Priv to truncate cannot be granted   |   --
    to truncate another user's       |  
    table; DROP ANY TABLE system     |   
    priv required                    |      
Storage for table and indexes can    |   Never shrinks the size of a 
    be set to initial size           |       table or indexes
Cannot truncate parent table from    |   --
    an established referential       |  
    integrity constraint; must       |  
    first disable foreign key        |  
    that references the parent       |  
    table                            |
```

Information compiled from this book: http://amzn.com/0470395125

Hopefully this may help any Oracle users that stumble across this page, as I did. Please feel free to point out which, if any, of these points hold true in MySQL,

Answer (score 2):

`DROP TABLE TableName` -> delete the table from the database.

`TRUNCATE TABLE TableName` -> delete the table's data, unconditionally... and reset the `IDENTITY` seed value, if the table has an `IDENTITY` field.

Answer (score 1):

- `DELETE`: DML command, if you perform delete command remove the only DATA without disrobing the table Structure we can ROLLBACK  the data row by row manner
- `TRUNCATE`: DDL command, if you perform Truncate  command remove the only DATA without disrobing the table Structure we can't rollback the data truncate remove the data in a PAGE BY PAGE manner truncate is faster then delete query
- `DROP`:, DDL command, if you perform the DROP command its delete(remove) the data and total table structure also we can't rollback the data